SEO impact: WP+Next.js hybrid
Our corporate website is a hybrid of Next.js and WP:

Next.js app uses data from WP database
WP works in the headless CMS mode

Does this integration affect SEO in any specific ways?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You might have more luck asking an SEO question like this on Webmasters SE.

Short answer is: Not in particular. Long answer is: there's a lot of potential affects.

Rendering: Next.js allows you to ship rendered html through static and SSR. This is important for performance generally and a best practice for SEO. Many search engines now render JS as part of crawling but its a mixed bag. So make sure Next.js is doing pre-rendering in one of these ways.

HTML head and SEO meta: Headless apps require you to think about adding SEO fields (meta, structured content, etc) to your front end. Installing RankMath or Yoast to WP will not automatically add the content they create to your pages in Next.js. If you're using WPGraphQL there are 3rd party plugins available for both these tools to integrate that data into your schema. They also both support the WordPress REST API. Either way, you'll use the provided data to add SEO metadata into your pages with Next.js.

Canonical URLs: URLs with headless WordPress get a little funky and you will want to make sure links and menus all point to your front end. Especially the canonical url in your site's metadata. Additionally, you'll want to make sure that you WordPress instance is not being indexed. If it has a working theme you'll need to make sure the server has a robots.txt or the appropriate headers to not be indexed. Beware, if you try to use Yoast or Rank Math's built in tools for this, that data might inadvertently get applied to the front end as well through the api integration.


